# Survey Force app error "Authorization required" thrown sometimes

Tags: force.com-sites, error, appexchange, error-messages

We are using Survey Force to send a survey to non-SF users and while some of them submit their answers without any issue, others are required to login in order to submit their answers.
We have checked all public sites settings and permissions and tried to reproduce the bug but never succeeded... So we are bit stuck and were wondering if others had a similar experience :)

Many thanks!
Luiza

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue and managed to fix it, will post here for future reference:

1. First, make sure the `Survey__c.Share_with_Guest_User__c` is checked.
2. Go to Sharing Settings > Survey Sharing Rule and see if there's something. If *yes*, then remove it and wait for it to be recalculated (SF will fire an e-mail to let you know).
3. After receiving the e-mail (or if it was empty), add a new rule for Guest Users: `Survey__c.Share_with_Guest_User__c equals true`. Wait for it to be recalculated.

It took me a long time to try this out, but it was what fixed for users who were being asked to login in my publicly available surveys.